# Passing a JSONObject as a parameter on Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jetty

I wish to implement a REST service using Spring MVC where I pass in the following object at the URL `"/url/lookup/{jsonparm}"`:

```
{"url":"http://bubba.com/foo/bar", "max_hops":3}
```

I tried the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url/lookup/{jsonparam}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String urlLookup(@PathVariable("jsonparam") String jsonparam) {
    // just to see if I can get the parms
    logger.debug("urlLookup get request : " + jsonparam.toString()); 
    JSONObject resp = new JSONObject();
    return resp.toString(); // return an empty JSONObject for now
}
```

So I invoke this by calling

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/wsp/url/lookup/%7B%22max_hops%22%3A3%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fbubba.com%2Ffoo%2Fbar%22%7D
```

No luck see the following in my Jetty log:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/v1/wsp/url/lookup/{"max_hops":3,"url":"http://bubba.com/foo/bar"}] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'
```

Notes:

1. the url prefix `localhost:8080/v1/wsp/` is correct and my Servlet and Request Mapping are also correct
2. I have updated the question to use a `@PathVariable` as one of the responders suggested

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing `GET` and `POST` methods.

Either:

1. Use `POST` method and actually *post* the JSON contents to the controller. You can debug this using any REST client, eg. [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for Chrome.
2. Use `GET` method (as you are currently). *But* you have to pass the JSON value as an actual parameter called `jsonparam`. So, your example should change to:

   ```
    http://localhost:8080/v1/wsp/url/lookup/jsonparam=%7B%22max_hops%22%3A3%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fbubba.com%2Ffoo%2Fbar%22%7D
   ```

The latter is less common.

---

**Edit:**

On second look at your URL, I suspect you're confusing two Spring annotations:

1. `@PathVariable("jsonparam")` and:
2. `@RequestParam("jsonparam")`

You're using `@RequestParam` while your URL indicates need for `@PathVariable`.

**Edit2:**

However, as can be read here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates the path variable can be passed a value of *any simple type*. I believe JSON isn't one of them, hence your problems.

I would strongly recommend using `POST` for interchanging JSON values. However, if that is not an option, I would recommend sticking with `GET` method, `@RequestParam` for accessing parameter value, and passing the JSON value like in the corrected example above.

Comment: many thanks I changed the code a bit:

 @RequestMapping(value = "/url/lookup/{jasonparam}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Should this not work now?

Comment: I wish to use a GET method and pass it as the last part of my url

Comment: @andre, thanks for your notes ... I fear you may be right. I am passing PathVariable as a String with the proper URL escape sequences ... so I reckon it should work no ?

Comment: @user1172468 doubt it, since I'm seeing anyone passing JSON in path variable for the first time. It was designed to pass simple strings, numbers and dates, etc. I still don't understand why wouldn't you use GET with actual param or POST - change method signature to `urlLookup(@RequestBody String jsonparam)` and call it with JSON in POST content *without escaping*.

Comment: @andre, ok let me try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use @PathVariable instead of @RequestParam:

```
public String urlLookup(@PathVariable("jsonparam") String jsonparam){
}
```

because you have @RequestMapping(value = "/url/lookup/**{jasonparam}**"

And you have a typo in your @RequestMapping value. It should be /url/lookup/**{jsonparam}** instead of {jasonparam}

Comment: Thanks ... this is what I wanted to do.

Comment: I tried this but I now get: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/v1/wsp/url/lookup/{"max_hops":3,"url":"http://bubba.com/foo/bar"}] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest' .... updating the question

Comment: typo? /url/lookup/{j**a**sonparam} but you have @PathVariable("jsonparam") String jsonparam

Comment: Yikes, thanks for pointing that out ... fixed that but still no luck :-(